# Export hotfixes to new computer?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, windows

Does anyone know how to export the hotfixes from one Windows Server 2008 R2 computer to another?

I'm building a copy of a windows machine and it would be helpful to me if there was a folder where they were all stored.

I found a question about how to list which ones were installed, but I couldn't find how to easily access the patches themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "official" solution is to set up a WSUS server.  Or, if that won't work for you, poke about in `%windir%\SoftwareDistribution\`.   The complication is that windows update service seems to cache the raw .CAB files, and doesn't keep the .MSI or .MSP packages handy.